# Visual Studio Code snippet suggest

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have the following snippets

```json
{
  "Fraction":{
    "prefix": "frac",
    "body": "\\\\frac{$1}{$2}$3"
  },
  "Squared":{
    "prefix": "sq",
    "body": "^2"
  }
}
```

I would like to type the following " "frac" + "TAB" + "x" + "TAB" +"y" + "x" + "spacebar" +"sq" "TAB" + "TAB" " and get the following

```js
\frac{x}{y ^2}
```

with my cursor at the end of sq}, but I get

```js
\frac{x}{y sq}
```

with my cursor being at the end of sq}. What I am noticing is that pressing "TAB" whilst in a snippet does not trigger other snippets, and instead, goes to the next placeholder.

**My question**: Is it possible to allow suggestions in snippets such as "TAB" executes them? I am aware that one can use "ctr+space" to manually enable the suggestions but I would like to know if one can do this whilst using tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable this setting:

`Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions`

The default is `enabled` which means you will **not** get other snippet suggestions until you have fully exited the current snippet.  Which is not what you want - so *uncheck* that setting.

Comment: and another duplicate answering?